# Unable to set header with Hapi.js reply

Tags: node.js, http-headers, hapi.js

when i add a random header to a reply in Hapi.js, it works fine.

However when I am trying to add to a header that already exisits, it is not sent.

It is almost as if i didn't even add it.

```
 reply("Hello World)
      .header("Random-Header", "Random Reply")
      .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Authorization");
```

Is there a way to add the Access-Control-Expose-Headers - Authorization?

Comment: You should configure the cors header via config on either server or route level and not directly like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use CORS headers you should enable/configure them in `route` options (CORS headers disabled by default):

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function(request, reply) { ... },
  config: {
    cors: {
      origin: ['*'], // list of valid domains
      exposedHeaders: ['Authorization'] // 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'
    }
  }
});
```

Read more about defaults and options in [hapi documentation](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options).

or you can enable CORS on all routes:

```
new Hapi.Server({
  connections: {
    routes: {
      cors: {
        origin: ['*'],
        exposedHeaders: ['Authorization']
      }
    }
  }
})
```